# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidr is not a function[Console Chrome developer tool]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I put this code into add basic module HTML block of a wordpress page builder. I encounter the white screen of death. Chrome developer console told me the following:

```
helpers.js?ver=4.5.3:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidr is not a function
```

This can be traced from line 15 in helpers.js?ver=4.5.3:

```
        $('#mobile-menu-trigger').sidr({
        source: sourceVal,
        name: 'sidr-main'
    });
```

Before or after I restored the previous version of the page, there was no such error. The html code below seems to run normally if save as a html file and open it with chrome. Can someone please explain which might have possibly caused that error?

Edit: When I change the theme of wordpress, everything works again. With all of other themes, the code works so the problem should come from the theme.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {       
       getUpdates();    
   });   
   function getUpdates() {
        
    // get the data with a webservice call
    $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/136053/feed/last.json?callback=?', function(data) {               
      // if the field1 has data update the page
      if (data.field1) {
          document.querySelector('.info-giver .temperature').innerHTML = data.field1.slice(0,4) + "°C";
          document.querySelector(".info-giver .humidity").innerHTML = data.field2.slice(0,5) + "%";
          document.querySelector('.info-giver .windspeed').innerHTML = data.field4.slice(0,4) +" m/s";
          document.querySelector(".info-giver .pressure").innerHTML = data.field3 +"Pa" ;           
      }              
    });
    
   }
   (jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "announcer">
<div class="temperatureDeclared" style= "width: 25.00%">Temperature</div>
<div class="humidityDeclared" style= "width: 25.00%">Humidity</div>
<div class="windspeedDeclared" style= "width: 25.00%">Windspeed</div>
<div class="pressureDeclared" style= "width: 25.00%">Pressure</div>
</div> 
<div class = "info-giver">
<div class="temperature" style= "width: 25.00%">N/a</div>
<div class="humidity" style= "width: 25.00%">N/a</div>
<div class="windspeed" style= "width: 25.00%">N/a</div>
<div class="pressure" style= "width: 25.00%">N/a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: clearly $.sidr isn't a function. likely because... nothing is defining it on `$`.... not a whole lot to go on here.

Comment: Whatever the `sidr` library is, it isn't included in the page?

Comment: I dont even know what it is but chrome console send me that line ... Can you please tell me what might it be?

Comment: it's something on your site. What is likely happening is you're including jquery twice, and that's screwing things up.

Comment: the helpers.js is certainly not my file. Any of its codes should be from another source hence I have no idea where the problem lies or which library should be included though. Is there any suggestion for where I should find those needed library ?

Comment: It may not be your file, but it's on **your** website.

Comment: I see. can I do something about this?

Comment: remove reference to the plugin or stop doing whatever is breaking it.

Comment: if I take the script away, things turn normal. So should I assume the html addon on beaver page builder does not allow me to have a script running?

Comment: Did you include the sidr library after JQuery by any chance?

Comment: No I did not. But hey, I suppose the problem was in one of our webpage plugin. Uninstalled it and now things are working fine !

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines before and after code your code will works

```
;(function($){
   //code
})(jQuery);
```

Just Like This

```
;(function($){
 $('#mobile-menu-trigger').sidr({
        source: sourceVal,
        name: 'sidr-main'
 });
})(jQuery);
```

I hope this will works !

Comment: thanks for your effort. When I tried it, it states in the console that sourceVal is not defined (Uncaught ReferenceError:) and the previous error persisted as well.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include your sidr library. After loading jquery include sidr library. After that init sidr like this on your html.

```
$('#mobile-menu-trigger').sidr({....});
```

Comment: should it be included in helpers.js or mine script? I tried to but it before $(document).ready(function() {  line and everything went N/a though.

Comment: did you include sidr library? if yes then your code should work. I have edited my answer. take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did include it in my file and run it but all the results turn N/a again though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you when I updated Contact Form 7 on WordPress.

Loading JQuery before calling sidr solved it.

```
// Load the jQuery library at the beginning.
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```